# how i use WP7 mobile in wireless-based indoors positioning system?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, positioning, wireless

can I use WP7 mobile in wireless-based indoors positioning system (i.e WIFI-based positioning system inside a building) ?

and if i can .. what about the type of map (for example vector map )

all of this in WP7 ..can I ?

Comment: What wireless positioning system are you talking about?? Your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Harsh! he means that the phone gets a GPS location using one of 3 things. The more it can use the more precise the location. 1 = cell tower, 2 = wireless locations (which is why google capture wireless info), 3 = GPS signal.

Comment: @Steve where in his question did he mention any of that? Your assuming that's what he means.

Comment: @loyalpenguin quite right - he never said any if that. Must stop making assumptions.

Comment: Here is some more info from one of his other questions: i need to position a mobile terminal inside a building using Wifi indoors positioning system that depends on detecting signal strength from the nearest access point to this mobile terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely to be very difficult to do this accurately with the current API.

There is only very little network information available to your application (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k056bfdz(v=VS.95).aspx)

One of the aims of the WP7 SDK/API was to make working with location simpler. This is why location information has been abstracted away behind the `GeoCoordinateWatcher`. This is not designed for providing location based purely on (private) WiFi network information.

If you are trying to develop an application that must be able to interact closely with wireless networks then WP7 is currently not an appropriate platform for doing this.